# jquery ajax in debian chromium gives error message 0

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When testing my application on ubuntu and the chromium browser everything works OK, but when moving to the production machine which uses debian and the same chromium browser, I always get an ajax error 0.

- jQuery version 1.7.2
- jQuery.mobile version 1.1.1
- Tomcat server

Request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/setvalue/1234",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(objResponse) {
        showMessage("Done");
    },
    error: errorHandler
});
```

The errorHandler gets called on the production machine, although the server processes the request correctly!

Thanks for any ideas...

Frank

------ ADDED ------

Alert shown with the code

```
function errorHandler(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
showAlert("Error", "Error: " + xhr.status + "\n" +
       "Message: " + xhr.statusText + "\n" +
       "Response: " + xhr.responseText + "\n" + thrownError); }
```

is:

*Error: 0*

*Message: error*

*Response:*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parenthesis is missing in the success function.

showMessage("Done"; should be showMessage("Done");

Could you check if this solves the problem?

**EDITED:**

My opinion is that the problem is not code related. Most probably the AJAX request in your case is considered as a cross domain request and the same origin policy fails. That's why you get Error:0.

I managed to reproduce the case (in Windows OS) and I'm getting the same error in the following cases:

1. Open my Web Page `http://localhost:7001/MobileApp/index.html` and perform AJAX on `http://www.example.com/MobileApp/test`.
2. Open my Web Page `http://localhost:7001/MobileApp/index.html` and perform AJAX on `http://127.0.0.1:7001/MobileApp/test`.
3. Open my Web Page `http://127.0.0.1:7001/MobileApp/index.html` and perform AJAX on `http://localhost:7001/MobileApp/test`
4. Open my Web Page `http://192.168.1.2:7001/MobileApp/index.html` (where 192.168.1.2 is my private IP address) and perform AJAX on `http://127.0.0.1:7001/MobileApp/test`.

The above cases were considered as cross domain requests and I got the the error you are mentioning.

Obviously after configuring my hosts file and mapping IP addresses to host names etc some of the above issues were resolved because the requests were not considered as cross domain.

In conclusion I would suggest to investigate whether the same origin policy succeeds.

[image]

Comment: no sorry, my mistake, I altered that during copy paste. That's OK in de application code

Comment: Hi. Can you plz post the exact error which appears? Is it just a zero? Is the AJAX request performed in the same domain?

Comment: One more question. In your production system you are using localhost in the AJAX's url?

Comment: I suppose that your Web Application is also running on  172.24.0.10:8080 right? Otherwise you have a cross-domain issue.

Comment: indeed on the same IP 172.24.0.10:8080/app/

Comment: I updated the post with some findings. My opinion is that the problem is not code related.